# How to redirect to login without add route to history record in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm on the page: `/foo` and click on the button to redirect me to `/bar`.
But I have beforeEach route event which redirect me to `/login`. after I do login, I redirect to `/bar`.

When I on `/bar` I click on the back button I get to login page. instend I want to get the the last page which is `/foo`.

How can I do it? is there a way to redirect to login without add route to history record?

```
  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (!to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.auth)) { return next(); }

    return next({
      path: '/login',
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use replace instead of push when you redirect to the page after login (in the login component).

```
loginSuccessed() {
 this.$router.replace(redirect);
}
```

Comment: what happens if you directly go to /login by typing it in the address bar and then call router.replace('/bar') will this have /bar as the first page now?

Answer (score 0):

Use route.replace insted of router.push. It acts like router.push, the only difference is that it navigates without pushing a new history entry, as its name suggests - it replaces the current entry.

```
succesffulyLoggedin() {
     this.$router.replace({ name: 'dashboard' });
}
```

read docs here [router replace](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

Comment: I added more explanation and source. Can you just appreciate it ? It may be helpful for some readers who visited this!